# What to do about questions that are near impossible to answer in the negative?

Tags: discussion

I asked [Do any nonLDS christian denominations belief in baptism after death?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/57589/do-any-nonlds-christian-denominations-belief-in-baptism-after-death) but then realized that if the answer is no, it would be nearly impossible to answer, without going thourgh every possible Christian denomination. Is that okay?

Comment: I think it's fine

Comment: Closely related: https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5708/21576

Comment: As it so happens, the question did have a positive answer.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think such questions are really a problem. Sure, proving a negative is nearly impossible. However somebody with good domain expertise should be able to make an educated assertion when something doesn't exist. At the very least they would be able to guess the scale at which it might exist. For example the question about denominations would not be that difficult to answer. Even with some research you are only going to come up with a handful of individuals and with small followings outside of LDS circles that believe that. None of them have become denominations of any notable size. Thus it would not be too hard to answer in the negative.

The usual rules apply. Questions which are too broad in the positive are also too broad in the negative. But given a specific enough question that domain expertise and a little bit of research could speak to, I don't think the question formulation is problematic.

Answer (score 2):

If you had phrased it like this:

"Which non-LDS Christian denominations believe in baptism after death(if any do)?"

Any answer would be limited to the affirmative case.

Comment: Do you think there is a fundamental problem with the original wording? The question is functionally the same, just dressed up in different trappings. The answers range of possible answers would be substantially the same. Even if you ask about the affirmative case, if no instances exist an answer to the question asserting that is still a valid answer.

Comment: @Caleb I am answering this question as asked. Either there will be no answers, or an answer will pop up *without going thourgh every possible Christian denomination*  That is the problem presented.

Comment: If that's the problem, I don't see how this solves it. The same research and answers would pass on either the original or your iteration with only minimal wording adjustments.

Comment: @Caleb You are free to disagree with me, we aren't losing or making money on this.  I offer a suggestion in an attempt to be helpful.  If you want to argue about it, you are welcome to argue with someone else.  I don't see this as worth any more time.  (Yours or mine).